# Why can't a struct impl await its task and get result when it can await its methods?

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

In some cases it would be useful for a struct/object to be able to start some tasks and then allow struct users to stop these tasks and await for result. I could of course send result with channel or shared resource but using return value would be cleaner in many cases. Also I understand from experience in other async languages that it is good practice to always await your tasks at some point in code.

I cannot make the borrow checker to accept the following attempt to implement the idea over. Can someone explain it? and even better can I find a way out of it?

```
use tokio::time;
use tokio::task::JoinError;

struct S {
    pub task: tokio::task::JoinHandle<bool>,
}

impl S {
    pub async fn new() -> Self {
        let task = tokio::task::spawn(async {
            time::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(10)).await;
            true
        });
        Self { task }
    }

    pub async fn join_and_get_result(&self) -> Result<bool, JoinError> {
        self.task.await // cannot move out of `self.task` which is behind a shared reference
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let s = S::new().await;
    s.join_and_get_result().await;
    let result = s.task.await; // this is fine for borrow checker but requires to expose internal implementation
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `.await` on a task consumes the task. You can fix the error by making `join_and_get_result` take `self` and not `&self`, which will move `S` into the function making it possible to call `.await` on the task:

```rust
use tokio::task::JoinError;
use tokio::time;

struct S {
    pub task: tokio::task::JoinHandle<bool>,
}

impl S {
    pub async fn new() -> Self {
        let task = tokio::task::spawn(async {
            time::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(10)).await;
            true
        });
        Self { task }
    }

    pub async fn join_and_get_result(self) -> Result<bool, JoinError> {
        self.task.await
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let s = S::new().await;
    let result = s.join_and_get_result();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=15c42ef841ee1de339a8fdd94d91cc31)

Comment: That was great. I completely missed that point. I though that using `self`was creating a copy, but in fact it consumes it, thus requiring a copy in some situations.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers, it's also possible to await `&mut JoinHandle<()>`, i.e.:

```rust
struct Wrap {
    handle: tokio::task::JoinHandle<()>,
}

impl Wrap {
    async fn wait_for_result(&mut self) -> Result<(), tokio::task::JoinError> {
        (&mut self.handle).await
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut wrap = Wrap {
        handle: tokio::spawn(async {}),
    };
    
    let _res = wrap.wait_for_result().await;
    drop(wrap); // wrap is not consumed, can be passed to drop()
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c98fd34b3a3e527751240a3143abddc2)

Note that when dealing with `tokio::spawn` & `JoinHandle` it's probably not desired to keep the `JoinHandle` around after awaiting it because another `await` will result in a panic:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'JoinHandle polled after completion', /playground/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/tokio-1.18.2/src/runtime/task/core.rs:212:22
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a7b102664516cd300a1b6facb69a8796)

It's e.g. useful when selecting both a `JoinHandle` and waiting for messages over some channel, i.e. something like

```rust
loop {
    tokio::select! { 
        res = &mut handle => {
            // deal with task outcome
            break;
        },
        msg = chan.recv() => {
            // react to msg, continue waiting for task or next msg
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to https://stackoverflow.com/a/72582847/2033030 , Another way to do it if someone does not want to consume the struct is to put the task in an option and consume the option

```
use tokio::time;

struct S {
    pub task: Option<tokio::task::JoinHandle<()>>,
}

impl S {
    pub async fn new() -> Self {
        let task = tokio::task::spawn(async {
            time::sleep(time::Duration::from_secs(10)).await;
        });
        Self { task: Some(task) }
    }

    pub async fn join(&mut self) {
        if self.task.is_some() {
            let task = self.task.take();
            task.unwrap().await.ok();
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut s = S::new().await;
    s.join().await;
}
```